# WordPress: Customize subject in new comment notification e-mails

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

What code should I use to customize the subject of notification e-mails in a WordPress blog?

I mean the e-mails sent to post authors when a comment has been left by someone on their post.

At the moment the subject is about:

> [%site-title%] Comment: "%post-title%"‏

I'd like to use:

> New comment is waiting for you

Current code in functions.php

```
function comment_moderation_post_author_only($emails, $comment_id)
{
$comment = get_comment($comment_id);
$post = get_post($comment->comment_post_ID);
$user = get_userdata($post->post_author);

// Return only the post author if the author can modify.
if ( user_can($user->ID, 'edit_comment', $comment_id) && !empty($user->user_email) )
    return array( $user->user_email );

return $emails;
}

add_filter('comment_moderation_recipients', 'comment_moderation_post_author_only', 11, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `comment_moderation_subject` filter :

```
add_filter('comment_moderation_subject', 'my_comment_moderation_notification_subject');
function my_comment_moderation_notification_subject($subject, $comment_id){
    return "New comment is waiting for you";
}
```

Comment: The answer remains unchanged ; you have to add this code in addition to what you already have in functions.php

Comment: Done, but I still get the standard subject.

Comment: Maybe try with a filter priority (to be sure that your code is executed last) : `add_filter('comment_moderation_subject', 'my_comment_moderation_notification_subject', 99);`

Answer (score 0):

looks like you needs to use filters .

Put below code in your functions.php

```
add_filter('comment_moderation_subject', 'temp_comment_moderation_notification_subject');
function temp_comment_moderation_notification_subject($subject, $comment_id){
    return "New comment is waiting for you";
}
```

Please refer below link - 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_moderation_subject/